# ARIMA forecast is so different to the actual value

Tags: python, time-series, prediction, arima, forecast

I have just used the ARIMA model to perform 24 steps forecast on the US unemployment rate. However, when it comes to visualisation, the predicted results are so much different compared to the actual values.....

Could anyone tell me which part I may have done wrong?
Thank you in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlKWK.png)

Comment: It looks like you just predict the residuals. To obtain the actual prediction, you have to add back the mean (and possibly trend and whatever else you may have removed before/during building the model) to those residuals.

Comment: Please don't use images for code